# Mysql in Joomla: Efficient multiple selects in one query and possible evaluation

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I'm trying to combine the following queries into one if possible, for effectiveness.

A form which is actually the question form of a quiz, it has a $quiz_id and a $user_id. This question has a foreign key attached to it, which is clue_id.

1. In the first query, I am selecting the clue_id for that specific quiz.
2. Then in the second query, I'm asking how many quizzes share the same clue_id? Return that as $count_quizes_with_this_clue.
3. In the last one, I'm counting how many quizzes have been answered and stored in a separate many-to-may relationship table (fab_ans_quest). This table has only the user_id and the quiz_id that it has been answered correctly.

As a result, I want to compare the count of point 2 and point 3. If equals, then it should do something.

Now, I am trying to make the above-mentioned sequence more efficient, by making it in one query. Even better, if it could even evaluate the result, resulting in true or false would be great!

Thanks!

```
$db =& JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query
    ->select($db->quoteName('clue_id'))
    ->from($db->quoteName('fab_puzzles'))
    ->where($db->quoteName('id') . ' = '. $db->quote($quiz_id));
$db->setQuery($query);
$clue_id = $db->loadResult();

$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query
    ->select('COUNT(*)')
    ->from($db->quoteName('fab_puzzles'))
    ->where($db->quoteName('clue_id') . ' = '. $db->quote($clue_id));
$db->setQuery($query);
$count_quizes_with_this_clue = $db->loadResult();

$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query
    ->select('COUNT(*)')
    ->from($db->quoteName('fab_puzzles', 'a'))
    ->join('INNER', $db->quoteName('fab_ans_quest', 'b') . ' ON (' . $db->quoteName('a.id') . ' = ' . $db->quoteName('b.quiz_id') . ')')
    ->where($db->quoteName('a.clue_id') . ' = '. $db->quote($clue_id) . ' AND ' . $db->quoteName('b.user_id') . ' = '. $db->quote($user_id));
$db->setQuery($query);
$count_completed_quizes_with_this_clue = $db->loadResult();
```

Comment: is this for a database table related to Joomla or a complete standalone table? If it's related to Joomla, i.e belongs to a component, then firstly, I would add a prefix to your table names in the query like so: `fab_puzzles` >> `#__fab_puzzles`

Comment: Hello Lodder, for now, they are standalone tables. I will add prefixes on a later stage! Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the $query object at all if you don't plan on using a different RDBMS in the near future.

You can just have:

```
$db =& JFactory::getDbo();
$sql = "SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ...";
$db->setQuery($sql);
$arr = $db->loadAssocList();
```

Comment: `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ...` >> old Joomla coding standards

Comment: Indeed, but indeed you never know! According to the Documentation of Joomla, it's a good practice they use: http://docs.joomla.org/Accessing_the_database_using_JDatabase

Comment: @mmystery - The way you're current doing it, such as `->select('')`, `->from('')` is the Joomla coding standard

Comment: Yeah! :) Any suggestion regarding the above-mentioned question?